# Pass a Javascript getter as a parameter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an ecma6/es2015 class with a getter defined like so:

```
get foo() { return this._foo; }
```

What I'd like to be able to do is pass that function as a parameter.  Making a call like so:

```
someFunction(myClass.foo);
```

will simply invoke the function.  Is there a clean way I can pass the method without invoking it and then invoke in the pass I'm passing it into?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume you'll have to wrap it into an anonymous function to keep it from getting executed:

```
someFunction(() => myClass.foo);
```

Or, you can get the getter function itself, but it is less readable than the above:

```
someFunction(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(myClass, 'foo').get);
```

Comment: That's the right idea I think.  How would I invoke the anonymous function inside of the method?

Comment: It's a normal function, just execute it (in both cases). `function someFunction(fooFunc) { var fooVal = fooFunc(); }`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood you do you mean a way to define the function and pass it later to another one (as a function) to be invoked later?

something like this?

```js
var myFunc = function() {
  console.log('func');
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML='func';
}

console.log( 'start');
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML='start';

setTimeout( myFunc, 3000 );
console.log( 'end');
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML='end';
```

```html
<h1 id='result'>default</h1>
```